# How can I tell if I have a C wire?

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Below is a photo of my current thermostat's wiring. I have a few questions:

1. Why is the RC and RH are bridged with a black wire?
2. I have an unused blue wire. Is there a way to find its function? Could it be the "C" wire?
   This is used to control Rheem force heat / AC unit.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jumper is installed between `Rh` and `Rc`, because your setup does not use two transformers.  `Rh` is powered from the heating system transformer, while `Rc` is powered from the cooling system transformer.  However, it's common to only have a single transformer for both systems. In which case, the jumper between the terminals may be required.

The only way to tell if and where the blue wire is connected, is to open up the furnace or air handler and have a look. Without knowing the exact model unit you have, it's not possible to tell you exactly what to look for.  Basically you'll want to follow the thermostat cable, and try to locate where the wires terminate inside the unit.